# Generar código de barras en email

Tags: html, css, laravel, email, código-de-barras

Estoy añadiendo un código de barras a código HTML pero resulta que no me generan los códigos cuando envío el código en un email. Si lo genero en un PDF o en HTML de una página normal no hay problemas, pero cuando lo hago en el email, no me aparece nada.

Estoy usando el paquete *Barcode/Milon* para Laravel 5.1. ¿A qué se puede deber esto?¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Document</title> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <p>
      <strong>Unidad solicitante: </strong>
      {!!$pedido->id!!}
    </p> 
    <div style="width: 500px !important;"> 
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($pedido->i‌​d, 'C39',5,60)}}" alt="barcode" />
    </div> 
    <br> 
    <div style="width: 500px !important;"> 
      {!!DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($pedido->id, 'C39')!!} 
    </div> 
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código con el que generas el código de barras?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p> <strong>Unidad solicitante: </strong>{!!$pedido->id!!}</p>

 <div style="width: 500px !important;">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($pedido->id, 'C39',5,60)}}" alt="barcode" />
 </div>
 <br>
 <div style="width: 500px !important;">
  {!!DNS1D::getBarcodeHTML($pedido->id, 'C39')!!}
 </div>
</html>

Comment: Ese vendria siendo, el html del email, para generar el codigo de barras simplemente llamo a esas clases, solo es necesario llamarlas y composer hace lo suyo.

Comment: No he trabajado en laravel, ¿por qué uno es `{!!DNS1D::...!!}` y el otro es `{{DNS1D::...}}`? ¿No funciona ninguno de los dos? ¿Puedes compartir el código que sí funciona?

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código del correo electrónico? es decir el menesaje que generas y estas mandando como cuerpo del correo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el código script no se va a ejecutar en el cliente de correo.

Lo más fácil que puedes hacer es poner una etiqueta img con un source a algún servicio que te genere ese código y lo devuelva como una imagen. Si vas a conseguir que te funcione en todos sitios, probarlo desde fuera e incluso, usarlo en otros proyectos. Algo así como hace esta gente: http://barcode.tec-it.com/es

Te dejo un ejemplo: http://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=ABC-abc-1234&code=Code128&dpi=96

Comment: De hecho lo intente pero no funcionó, acabo de realizar otra opción, la cual consistió en enviar un pdf con todo el contenido, a fin de cuentas igual me servia esa opción. Gracias por la ayuda, igual seguiré intentando de otras formas :)